# Where to store client_id and client_secret for rest API in Xamarin Forms

Tags: security, xamarin.forms

Recently, I've been tackling security issues where in my app can be compromised by getting my client_id and client_secret.

My implementation was storing the config data in a config file(App.config) using `PCLAppConfig` plugin. Overview on this is you will create a config file which build action was as Embedded Resource.

I thought that was safe enough since it is stored in a config file, after my friend tried to penetration testing on my app. Basically he just do the following:

1. Download the app in the Google Play Store (example for Android)
2. Get the apk equivalent. (He use Share It)
3. Rename the .apk file to .zip
4. Open using a Reflection Tool and you will see all the dll files. He then see that under the dll files(PCL class) he can see the .config file.

At that moment he knows all confidential data that should not be known to users.

My question is, how to securely store those confidential data. It should not be hardcoded since all the codes where converted to .dll file and can be track using Reflection Tool.

**UPDATE**

Still no solution

Comment: Does your app use a login?

Comment: @Johannes, no it does not have but we have oauth2 authentication using client_id and client_secret so no one can access the api if they dont have the 2

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use SecureStorage from Xamarin Essentials

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android

...

```
try
{
  await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_token", "secret-oauth-token-value");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use encryption for your keys.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16071/encryption-decryption-in-xamarin

Comment: keys are already encrypted. i just need to store them which I dont know where.

Comment: Secure storage in your case?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android

Comment: You do not want to store your secret key with your app as anyone can easily get through your api calls. 

If your app having a login ID and password, return app key and secret from database using sign in and store in the device after successful login.
Same as JWT token base authentication.

Comment: yes thats it, so how can I do it without putting my client_id and client_secret in such a way it is not hardcoded. it could be at build time it will read in some files right. the options you give where not belong on any of this